# Drawing tickets from a hat

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve this question.

> Suppose we draw two tickets from a hat that contains tickets numbered 1, 2, 3, 4. Let $X$ be the first number drawn and $Y$ be the second. Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Find their marginal distributions, and $P(X = n|Y = m)$.

I'm wondering if I've solved it right. I don't have a solutions manual to my textbook and I can't find another question like this. Here is what I've done.

Assuming no replacement, $P(X=n|Y=m)=0\; \forall$ n=m.

$P(X=1|Y=2)= \frac{P(X=1)P(Y=2|X=1)}{P(Y=2)}=\frac{P(X=1)P(Y=2|X=1)}{P(X=1)P(Y=2|X=1)+P(X=2)P(Y=2|X=2)+P(X=3)P(Y=2|X=3)+P(X=4)P(Y=2|X=4)} = \frac{(\frac{1}{4})(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{4})}{3\cdot(\frac{1}{4})(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{4})}=\frac{1}{3}$

A similar argument can be made for all other pairs (X,Y).

Therefore,
$P(X=n|Y=m) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{3}, & n \neq m, \\
  0, & n=m.
\end{cases}$

Now, to find the marginal distribution, I'll use $p_{X}(x)=\sum_{y=1}^{4}p_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

$p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{12}, & x \neq y, \\
  0, & x=y.
\end{cases}$

This would mean that $\; p_{X}(x)=\sum_{y=1}^{4}p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}=p_{Y}(y) \; \forall \; x,y$.

Is this right?

Comment: It is correct. Could have been done faster. For example, by symmetry we have $f_X(x)=1/4$ for $x=1,2,3,4$.  A similar appeal to symmetry deals with $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.